# How to pass GET request to window.location in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a script that is supposed to get the username and go to another page with that username in URL, like this: `www.site.com/members/?username=john`. How can this be done with javascript? I have my current code like this

```
<script> 

window.location = 'www.site.com/members/?{$member.username}';

</script>
```

What this does is www.site.com/members/?john but I need to pass assign parameter as GET request. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you need this? `window.location = 'www.site.com/members?username={$member.username}';`  ?

Comment: How about `window.location = 'www.site.com/members/?username={$member.username}';`? It's hard to tell. Please provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create a string with the required location in it:

```
<script>
window.location = 'www.site.com/members/?username=' + username_variable;
</script>
```

Or your way of doing it (using ES6 formatting):

```
<script>
window.location = 'www.site.com/members/?username={$member.username}';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose member.username is a working variable with the username.

```
<script>
//..

window.location = 'www.site.com/members/?'+member.username+'';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is client-side technology, it cannot get any data by itself. Try to make ajax call to a server-side REST API and get the data back.